# Firefox Nightly Google Search Bar shrunk

Tags: firefox, google-search, searchbar, nightly-build

I have the latest update for Nightly (34.0a1 (2014-08-14)). It addressed one of the two problems I have from the previous update, which was the disappearing input fields. The other problem was the shrinking of the Google search field. What can I do to fix this?
[See screenshot here.](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=14wpis&s=8#.U-3qMnvQ3PY)

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051511, but stackoverflow really isn't the right place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

@Acnologia, we are aware of the issue and have logged a bug with Google for them to fix the issue. You can follow along on [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1051511) if you need more details.

Answer (score -1):

The way I worked around the problem was to close Nightly, open Internet Explorer, and then re-download Firefox Nightly over the version I already have (DO NOT DEINSTALL!). Apparently it reset the version back to "34.0a1 (2014-07-21)" - before the "Google Search Results Page Searchbar Too Small" issue started. Then each time I start Nightly and Windows7 asks me if I want to allow the application to make changes to my computer, I answer "No" so Nightly does not get updated.

Then, each evening after I get home from work, I Google the past 24 hours to see if the issue has been fixed yet, and I will not update Nightly again until it has.

I realize this is a cheap workaround, and I would love to be able to trust Nightly Updates again, but this common issue should have been foreseen before the build was released. - And I will give them another week or two to figure it out, and if not... bye, bye Nightly!